# ActiveMQ "Classic" Jakarta EE namespace support

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, spring-camel

We are evaluating option to update ActiveMQ "Classic" from 5.16.5 to 5.18.2 which has Jakarta namespace support.

I could not find the 5.18.2 version available for the `activemq-camel` jar on Maven repo. The latest version available for `activemq-camel` is 5.16.5 which has references to old `javax` package.

Has anyone faced similar issue?

Any recommendation is welcome.

Comment: Apache Camel support for Jakarta is coming in Camel v4.x

Comment: For what it's worth, [ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/) has _full_ support for Jakarta Messaging 3.1. This support was implemented over a year ago now. At this point ActiveMQ "Classic" only has a partially functioning implementation of JMS 2 and therefore only a partially functioning implementation of Jakarta Messaging 3.1. You can find more details [here](https://activemq.apache.org/jms2).

Answer (score 2):

The `activemq-camel` module was removed from the ActiveMQ code-base in early 2022 via [AMQ-8457](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-8457). You are recommended to use one of the following instead:

- [`camel-jms`](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.21.x/jms-component.html)
- [`sjms`](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.21.x/sjms-component.html)
- [`sjms2`](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.21.x/sjms2-component.html)